# How to make an active link in the page in Odoo

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-8

I need to make sure that the menu was selected for this page.
Menu is more than 20 pages. For each write is not an option.

```
<ul name="cabinet-menu">
    <li class="menu-messages"><a href="/page/messages">Messages<span id="count_unread" value="count_unread"></span></a></li>
    <li class="menu-profile"><a href="/page/personal_profile" class="active">Profile</a></li>
    <li class="menu-iqub"><a href="/page/price_quotation">My Quotes</a></li>
    <li class="menu-blog"><a href="/page/blog_articles">Blog</a></li>
</ul>
```

UPD. I want the menu item to be highlighted when I are on the matching page

How do this?

Comment: Clarify your question: you want the menu item to be highlighted when you are on the matching page? Or what?

Answer (score 0):

odoo sets "main_object" variable: use that.

Your menu should be created in a way similar to this:

```
<t t-foreach="pages" t-as="page">
    <a t-att-class="page.id == main_object.id and 'active" [...]
</t>
```

If you are using Odoo's menu items [do like they do](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/website/views/website_templates.xml#L62), using url:

```
<li t-if="not submenu.child_id" t-att-class="
    'active' if submenu.url and submenu.url != '/' and request.httprequest.path == submenu.url.replace('/page/website.', '/page/') else None
    ">
    <a t-att-href="(website.menu_id.child_id[0] == submenu) and '/' or submenu.url" t-ignore="true" t-att-target="'_blank' if submenu.new_window else None">
        <span t-field="submenu.name"/>
    </a>
</li>
```